# Log files with fbcmd ADDPICD command?

Tags: facebook

[fbcmd](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/) allows one to interact with Facebook from the command line. The `ADDPICD` command adds a directory of .jpg photos to an album. Is there a way to log the progress as the files are transferred or report a list at completion by filename?

Answer (score 1):

FBCmd development has now stopped, so the answer is probably a resounding no at this point. :/

Sources:

- http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/
- https://apps.facebook.com/cmdline/
- https://apps.facebook.com/cmdline/

Comment: This type of answer is always better if you can cite a source.  BTW, if you were a Linux user, you'd know that development status doesn't mean anything.  In Linux, nothing is ever done being developed, and much of what is available is not actively being developed.  :-)

Comment: http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/
https://apps.facebook.com/cmdline/
https://www.facebook.com/cmdlinepage?fref=ts&ref=br_tf

[Sure wish the  on-screen help here explained why I can't insert line breaks into my comment, after 5 edits i give up]